# i18n and Drupal Search issue

Tags: 7, search, i18n-l10n

### As it stands

I am currently developing a multilingual website using Drupal 7 and the i18n module.

### The problem

When i do a search using drupals built in search form it is returning content for all languages, rather than just for the currently selected language (as i would expect it too).

### What i need

I need the search to only return results for the currently selected language.

Thanks in advance for your time.